# What is the proper use of KeyListener?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, keylistener

So I have been working on trying to extract the data in my jTextFields and this error message keeps popping up referring to an:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: calcu.turkey (<--my class) cannot be cast to java.awt.event.KeyListener`

```
      jTextField2.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
            //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
          //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
            //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });
    jTextField2.addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);
    jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 10)); // NOI18N
    jTextField2.setText("0");
    getContentPane().add(jTextField2);
    jTextField2.setBounds(250, 40, 70, 20);
```

Most importantly this line: `jTextField2.addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);` as it views the (KeyListener) as an error. I was wondering how do you properly add the KeyListener so it grab the number in the textfield.

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial. Implementing a Key Listener, or Action Listener is covered in the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use a KeyListener. Rarely do you have a need to do this. There are better API's to be used.

For example when using a text component you would probably use a `DocumentListener` (see [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)) or `DocumentFilter` (see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)).

> I was wondering how do you properly add the KeyListener so it grab the number in the textfield.

Normally you would grab the number on some unrelated event. For example you have a "Submit" button on a form. Then in that case you would add an ActionListener to the button and then use the `getText()` method of the text field when you want to submit the form.

Also, the Swing tutorial that I referenced above has a section on `How to Write a Key Listener`.

Comment: is there no way to make it automatically refresh with the answer? Does that make a lot of problems?

Comment: @Potatoesforfish, what are you talking about? What do you want to referesh?

Comment: The numbers get taken and crunched into an equation to produce an answer. If I did it your way, I would have to press the button each time I wanted to compute the answer.

Comment: @Potatoesforfish, `I would have to press the button each time I wanted to compute the answer` - how do you know when the user has finished entering the number? If you equation has more than one number, how do you know when all the numbers have a valid value. This is the situation when you would use a "Calculate" button. `If I did it your way` - If all fields always have valid information and you want to recalculate every time a single digit is change then my way (the better way) is to use a DocumentListener NOT a KeyListener.

Comment: I cannot find a DocumentListener in my library or in Net Beans IDE... Is there a package for this?

Comment: Did you look at the tutorial for the working example? Its in javax.swing.text.*.

Answer (score 2):

1. You get the error because your class does not implement the `KeyListener` interface. You will need to have a class declaration like `public class turkey implements KeyListener` and then in your class you need to implement all the methods defined by the `KeyListener` interface.
2. The correct way is not to use a `KeyListener` for `JTextField` (or any `JTextComponent`) for that matter. Use a `DocumentListener` or `DocumentFilter` (depends a bit on your use-case)
3. Not sure why you added the anonymous `KeyListener` to your text field and then want to add your class instance as `KeyListener` as well

Answer (score -1):

```
jTextField2.addKeyListener((KeyListener) this);
```

The above line is the culprit. Seems like your class is not implementing a `KeyListener`
Infact, I think you don't need that line at all, as you already attached an `KeyListener` to `jTextField2` by doing `jTextField2.addKeyListener(new ...`

Inside any of the below 3 methods, you can use ke.getKeyCode() or ke.getKeyChar() to retrieve the Key that was pressed.

```
@Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
      //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
```

Comment: "My class is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPreformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener" is the culprit now.

Comment: @Potatoesforfish That error message is pretty clear. If you do not understand it, I would suggest you start with a book/tutorial about the basics in Object Oriented programming / Java

Comment: Your class doesn't need to implement the ActionListener. I was infact referring to KeyListener.