# DocumentListener or KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener, documentlistener

It is mentioned in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890963/java-keylistener-how-to-detect-if-any-key-is-pressed) and in answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097750/what-is-the-proper-use-of-keylistener) that `documentListener` or `documentFilter` should be used rather than `keyListener`. Why is this?

Within a simple Hangman game I had been writing the other day I had done something like the code below:

```
public class Hangman extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    private JTextField guess;
    private JButton b1;
    private void addComponentsToPane(){
        b1 = new JButton("New Game");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        guess = new JTextField(2);
        guess.addKeyListener(this);
```

Later in the code I used `keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)` to get text input from the `JTextField` and `actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` for the `JButton`.

My question is, should  `documentListener`/`documentFilter` be used rather than `keyListener`, and **why** or **why not**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- KeyListener -- you should almost *never* use this with a text component as it is a low-level construct and can mess up the functioning of the text component.
- DocumentListener -- use this if you're not going to filter the input -- if you're going to accept all input presented but just want to keep track of input.
- DocumentFilter -- use if you are going to filter the input prior to display.

Myself, I'd use a DocumentFilter since this way I can ignore non-letter input. And I also second all that Kevin mentioned. 1+ to his answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer with a question: what should happen if you run your program on a system that uses the middle mouse button as a "paste" command? Some versions of Linux do this, for example.

In that case, a user can paste text into the JTextField, and your program will not detect it.

There are a bunch of corner cases like this, so although your KeyListener might work most of the time, you shouldn't rely on it for stuff that matters- otherwise you'll have a bunch of confused and annoyed users.